# Sift through each row in a dataframe and manually classify it

Tags: r, dataframe

Can someone recommend an efficient way to sift through each row in a dataframe and manually classify it?  For example I might be wanting to separate spam from e-mail, or shortlist job adverts, job applicants, or dating agency profiles (I understand Tinder does this by getting you to swipe left or right).

My dataset is small enough to classify manually.  I suppose if it was larger I might only want to manually classify a portion of it in order to train a machine-learning algorithm such as Naive Bayes to finish the task for me.

I'll show you what I've got at the moment, but this isn't a particularly original task, so there must be a less crude way to do this that someone has already thought of!  (As a newcomer, I'm impressed by the power of R, but also nonplussed when little tasks like clearing the screen or capturing a keystroke turn out to be non-trivial)

```
# Let us suppose I am using this built-in dataset to draw up a
# shortlist of where I might wish to go on holiday
df <- data.frame(state.x77);

# pp - define a task-specific pretty print function
pp <- function(row) {
    print(row); # Example dataset is simple enough to just print the entire row
}

# cls - clear the screen (this hack works on Windows but I've commented it for now)
cls <- function() {
    #system("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command (New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys([string][char]12)");
}

# It would halve the number of keystrokes needed if I knew a way to read
# a single character
readcharacter <- readline;

sift <- function(df, pp)
{
    classification = rep('', nrow(df));

    for (nRow in 1:nrow(df))
    {
        cls();
        pp(df[nRow,]);
        cat("\nEnter 'a' to discard, 'd' to keep, 'q' to quit\n");

        char <- '';
        while (char != 'a' && char != 'd' && char != 'q') {
            char <- readcharacter();
        }

        if (char == 'q')
            break;

        classification[nRow] = char;
    }

    return(cbind(df,classification=classification));
}

result = sift(df, pp);

cls();
cat("Shortlist:\n");
print(row.names(result[result$classification=='d',]));
```

Answer (score 0):

So how does the StackOverflow community feel about me using [this Shiny app](https://antony74.shinyapps.io/shortlist/) to solve my problem?  I wouldn't expect to see Shiny used in this early part of data analysis - normally it only comes into play once we have some results we'd like to explore or present dynamically.

Learning Shiny was fun and useful, but I'd much prefer it if a less complicated answer could be found.

```
library(shiny);

#
# shortlist - function that allows us to shortlist through the rows in a data frame efficiently
#
shortlist <- function(df, sTitle, sRowName) {

    createUI <- function() {

        listHeading <- list(
                    textOutput(outputId = "Progress"),
                    tags$br(),
                    fluidRow(
                        column(width=1, sRowName),
                        column(width=9, textOutput(outputId = "RowName"))));

        listFields <- lapply(names(df), function(sFieldname) {

            return(fluidRow(
                column(width=1, sFieldname),
                column(width=9, textOutput(outputId = sFieldname))));
        });

        listInputs <- list(
                    tags$br(),
                    tags$table(
                        tags$tr(
                            tags$td(" "),
                            tags$td(actionButton(inputId="Up", label="W", disabled=TRUE, width="100%"))),
                        tags$tr(
                            tags$td(width="100px", actionButton(inputId="Discard", label="Discard, A", width="100%")),
                            tags$td(width="100px", actionButton(inputId="Down", label="S", disabled=TRUE, width="100%")),
                            tags$td(width="100px", actionButton(inputId="Keep", label="Keep, D", width="100%")))),
                        tags$script("

                            // JavaScript implemented keyboard shortcuts, including lots of conditions to
                            // ensure we're finished processing one keystroke before we start the next.

                            var bReady = false;

                            $(document).on('shiny:recalculating', function(event) {
                                bReady = false;
                            });

                            $(document).on('shiny:recalculated', function(event) {
                                setTimeout(function() {bReady = true;}, 500);
                            });

                            $(document).on('keypress', function(event) {

                                if (bReady) {

                                    switch(event.key.toLowerCase()) {
                                    case 'a':
                                        document.getElementById('Discard').click();
                                        bReady = false;
                                        break;
                                    case 'd':
                                        document.getElementById('Keep').click();
                                        bReady = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            // End of JavaScript

                        "));

        listPanel <- list(
                    title = sTitle,
                    tags$br(),
                    conditionalPanel(
                        condition = paste("input.Keep + input.Discard <", nrow(df)),
                        append(append(listHeading, listFields), listInputs)));

        listShortlist <- list(
                    tags$hr(),
                    tags$h4("Shortlist:"),
                    dataTableOutput(outputId="Shortlist"));

        ui <- do.call(fluidPage, append(listPanel, listShortlist));

        return(ui);
    }

    app <- shinyApp(ui = createUI(), server = function(input, output) {

        classification <- rep('', nrow(df));

        getRow <- reactive({

            return (input$Keep + input$Discard + 1);
        });

        classifyRow <- function(nRow, char) {

            if (nRow <= nrow(df)) {
                classification[nRow] <<- char;
            }

            # In interactive mode, automatically stop the app when we're finished
            if ( interactive() && nRow >= nrow(df) ) {
                stopApp(classification);
            }
        }

        observeEvent(input$Discard, {classifyRow(getRow() - 1, 'a')});
        observeEvent(input$Keep,    {classifyRow(getRow() - 1, 'd')});

        output$Progress = renderText({paste("Showing record", getRow(), "of", nrow(df))});
        output$RowName  = renderText({row.names(df)[getRow()]});

        lapply(names(df), function(sFieldname) {
            output[[sFieldname]] <- renderText({df[getRow(), sFieldname]});
        });

        output$Shortlist <- renderDataTable(options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE), {

            # Mention the 'keep' input to ensure this code is called when the 'keep' button
            # is pressed.  That way the shortlist gets updated when an item to be added to it.
            dummy <- input$Keep;

            # Construct the shortlist
            shortlist <- data.frame(row.names(df[classification == 'd',]));
            colnames(shortlist) <- sRowName;
            return(shortlist);
        });

    });

    if (interactive()) {
        classification <- runApp(app);

        return(cbind(df, classification = classification));
    } else {
        return(app);
    }
}

#
# And now some example code.
# Shortlist the built in state.x77 data set (let us suppose I am drawing up
# a shortlist of where I might wish to go on holiday)
#

df <- data.frame(state.x77);

result <- shortlist(df = df, "Choose states", "State");

if (interactive()) {
    cat("Shortlist:\n");
    print(row.names(result[result$classification == 'd',]));
} else {
    return (result);
}
```